# Please help identify these bricks with holes between the rows of studs

Tags: part-identification, clone-brands

Hi I came across these bricks. But I have no idea what they are.
They are plastic as far as I can tell.

I hope someone knows a bit more

[image: bricks with holes between the rows of studs]

Answer (score 5):

These are early IDEMA bricks. http://www.inverso.pt/legos/clones/texts/idema.htm

Photo from linked site:

[image]

Comment: The site mentions "The middle holes are a feature patented by Dehm to allow a string to be passed through aligned holes, to fasten bricks together"